# :not selector doesn't hit children

Tags: css

I am unable to get :not working, been reading about it on css-tricks.

My Html:

```
 <div class="small-radio-slider" data-slider="slide" data-slider-active="0" data-slider-resetto="left">
   <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="inner" data-slider-container="true">
       <div class="slider-content">
         <div class="li noTextNoHiddenText" data-slide-index="{{@index}}">
           <div class="spotWrapper hiddenText">Not Me</div>
         </div>
         <div class="li noTextNoHiddenText" data-slide-index="{{@index}}">
           <div class="spotWrapper hiddenText">Not Me</div>
         </div>
         <div class="li noTextNoHiddenText" data-slide-index="{{@index}}">
           <div class="spotWrapper hiddenText">Not Me</div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="spotWrapper hiddenText">Me</div>
```

I need it to hit spotWrapper but not when it is inside NotextNoHiddenText..

But i am unable to get it to work with

```
.li:not(.noTextNoHiddenText) .spotWrapper {
    some styling which should only hit spotwrapper without .noText around it.
 }
```

**To clarify**

SpotWrapper is a partial of some boxes, which i use other places on a site. 
I also have a slider, which uses these boxes.

I need to make styling changes to the boxes, but NOT inside of the slider. 
So i have added the class noTextNoHiddenText to the box wrapper inside the slider.

```css
.li:not(.noTextNoHiddenText) .spotWrapper {
    color: red;
 }
```

```html
<div class="small-radio-slider" data-slider="slide" data-slider-active="0" data-slider-resetto="left">
       <div class="wrapper">
         <div class="inner" data-slider-container="true">
           <div class="slider-content">
             <div class="li noTextNoHiddenText" data-slide-index="{{@index}}">
               <div class="spotWrapper hiddenText">Not Me</div>
             </div>
             <div class="li noTextNoHiddenText" data-slide-index="{{@index}}">
               <div class="spotWrapper hiddenText">Not Me</div>
             </div>
             <div class="li noTextNoHiddenText" data-slide-index="{{@index}}">
               <div class="spotWrapper hiddenText">Not Me</div>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="spotWrapper hiddenText">Me</div>
```

**Answer**
Thank you to Mohammed Elshennawy for actually figuring it out, and understanding what i meant...

```
div:not(.noTextNoHiddenText) > .spotWrapper
```

Comment: which is why kids these days have no discipline!

Comment: Can you share it as fiddle ? I suspect it is getting overridden by some other element.

Comment: and all your `.li` have the class `noTextNoHiddenText` .. did you notice this ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif all my.li in this instance which should not be hit, has this class yes.

Comment: so ? :) everything is fine with your code

Comment: Except it doesn't work.

Comment: it does ;) none of the element will be target by this rule since all of them have this class :)

Comment: But i doesn't hit spotWrapper which is outside of small-radio-slider ?

Comment: becuase it's outside and has nothing to do with them

Comment: Then how can i style spotwrapper without hitting the spotwrapper which is inside the slider ? The boxes "spotwrapper" are used on many different pages, so i would like not to have to write code for each page to make it specific...

Comment: well  you add a custom class to avoid the change ... why not simply add a custom class to apply the change!

Comment: Because then i would have to add a class for 20 different pages, instead of applying the styling for the specific partial view. And then the only time it shouldn't hit is the slider..

Comment: I do not understand getting down votes for serious questions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS should be like this:-

```
:not(.noTextNoHiddenText) > .spotWrapper {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Sample [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/CzQPjqmtSGcqPtmpzUto?p=preview)

```css
.li:not(.noTextNoHiddenText) .spotWrapper {
  background-color: red;
}
:not(.noTextNoHiddenText) > .spotWrapper {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.2.1" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="small-radio-slider" data-slider="slide" data-slider-active="0" data-slider-resetto="left">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="inner" data-slider-container="true">
        <div class="slider-content">
          <div class="li noTextNoHiddenText" data-slide-index="{{@index}}">
            <div class="spotWrapper hiddenText">Not Me</div>
          </div>
          <div class="li noTextNoHiddenText" data-slide-index="{{@index}}">
            <div class="spotWrapper hiddenText">Not Me</div>
          </div>
          <div class="li noTextNoHiddenText" data-slide-index="{{@index}}">
            <div class="spotWrapper hiddenText">Not Me</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="li">
    <div class="spotWrapper hiddenText">Me</div>
  </div>
  <div class="spotWrapper hiddenText">Me</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: YES !! that works... so it actually was just the css not working... All those downvotes for a serious question... well.. Upvote for you ! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse your approach to it. Apply some default styling to `spotWrapper` and if its parent element is `noTextNoHiddenText` have another style.

Sample [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t05mnygt/1/)

-Help :)

Comment: Bind your custom boxes with other class and style them accordingly

Comment: SpotWrapper is a partial view, which is used on multiple pages, including a slider. But i do not want to hit the slider. Just all the other boxes.